# Firefox - don't allow to exit fullscreen mode via mouse clicking/ touching

Tags: firefox

Is it possible to prevent Firefox (latest version V59) to exit the Fullscreen mode/ to show the other opened tabs if the user clicks in the top left corner of the screen? (on a Windows Touch PC)

The only way to exit the fullscreen mode should be pressing F11.

Is there some entry in about:config to adjust the behaviour ?